# javaScript show hide feature has some issue displaying accordion which takes data from phpMyAdmin

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, accordion

I have made accordion and i don't know why i am seeing plain text without any CSS or JavaScript functionality in it.
i made sure that the link shown for cascading style sheet and JavaScript were working.
Later on my task is to make a table in mysql and import data from there but first i want to solve this problem sir. I am also not getting any error in which i can work on.

Here is my code

```
 <?php   
$arr_content = array(
array('title' =>  'Section 1',
      'content'=> 'Section 1 intro here'
),

array('title' =>  'Section 2',
      'content'=> 'Section 2 intro here'
),


array('title' =>  'Section 3',
      'content'=> 'Section 3 intro here'
),



);
 ?>  


<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Accordion</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href= 
         "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
           /3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

           <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />  
           <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>  
      </head>  




     <body>  
           <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-
           multiselectable="true">
       <?php $i=1; foreach($arr_content as $acontent) {  ?>
      <div class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne <?php echo $i; ?
        >">
      <h4 class="panel-title">


       <a <?php if($i>1) echo 'class="collapsed" ';?>
       role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent
        ="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $i;
       ?>" aria-expanded ="<?php echo ($i==1) ? 'true'
        :'false'; ?>true" aria-controls="collapse
        <?php echo $i; ?>">




        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
      <div id="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse <?
       php 
         if($i==1) echo 'in';
       ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading <?php echo $i; ?>">
        <div class="panel-body">
       <?php echo $acontent['content']; ?>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  <?php $i++; } ?>



 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</div>
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included bootstrap css twice, as well as js twice. And I cleaned up the code a bit. Hope this helps.

```
    <?php   
    $arr_content = array(
    array('title' =>  'Section 1',
          'content'=> 'Section 1 intro here'
    ),

    array('title' =>  'Section 2',
          'content'=> 'Section 2 intro here'
    ),


    array('title' =>  'Section 3',
          'content'=> 'Section 3 intro here'
    ),


    );
     ?>  
    <html>  
          <head>  
               <title>Accordion</title>  
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          </head>  

         <body>          
           <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
           <?php $i=1; foreach($arr_content as $acontent) {  ?>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $acontent['title']; ?></a>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse <?php if($i === 1) { echo " in "; } ?>">
                    <div class="panel-body"><?php echo $acontent['content']; ?></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <?php $i++; } ?>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

          </body>  
     </html>
```

Comment: yeah now i am getting good output but the collapse feature is not working.

Comment: can you suggest what .js file should i include from website.. I think the script src link is not working for my code.

Comment: Sorry!  Edited the answer. Do check it out now.

Comment: Sir Thanks a lot. What did you do by the way ?

Comment: Instead of local library scripts, included the same from the source.